# Viewing dask graph from a dask object

Tags: python, dask

In Matthew Rocklin's [presentation](http://conference.scipy.org/proceedings/scipy2015/pdfs/matthew_rocklin.pdf) on Dask (2015), he shows an example for viewing the [dask graph](https://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/graphs.html) underlying a `dask.array`:

[image]

It seems that the representation of that property has changed a bit since:

```
import dask.array as da
x = da.arange(15, chunks=(5,))
print(x.dask)
# <dask.sharedict.ShareDict object at 0x000001FD8869C2E8>

for k, v in x.dask.items():
    print(k)
    print(v)
    print()
# ('arange-367e8f921d6d8a8e494d9e8e9a7f5425', 0)
# (<function arange at 0x000001FD8857D158>, 0, 5, 1, 5, dtype('int32'))
# 
# ('arange-367e8f921d6d8a8e494d9e8e9a7f5425', 1)
# (<function arange at 0x000001FD8857D158>, 5, 10, 1, 5, dtype('int32'))
# 
# ('arange-367e8f921d6d8a8e494d9e8e9a7f5425', 2)
# (<function arange at 0x000001FD8857D158>, 10, 15, 1, 5, dtype('int32'))
```

How can I reproduce the behavior to view the basic (old) form of `dask.graph` from above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert `ShareDict` objects into normal `dict` objects by calling `dict` on them.

```
>>> dict(x.dask)
```

However, the output will be more verbose than with past versions (as displayed in the paper.)  The current version however is safer in a variety of respects, even if it is less aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: So, when I do that, I get the slightly messier representation above (from printing over the iterable `x.dask.items()`.  Is there a way to get to the more pared-down version from your paper?

Comment: Basically, it looks like they actually have the same structure but, for instance, 'x' is replaced by 'arange-367e8f921d6d8...'.

Comment: In brief, no, not with current versions.  The current version however is safer in a variety of respects, even if it is less aestheticly pleasing.